# Is there any alternative to the now-missing “AppleScript handler” option in Messages that allows playing custom sounds depending on sender?

Tags: macos, applescript, messages, high-sierra

In the Messages app, starting with the MacOS 10.13.4 upgrade Apple has removed the "AppleScript handler" option, which I had formerly used to play custom notification sounds when new messages were received from certain specific users (the feature removal confirmed today in a telephone conversation with an Apple Care rep, after I had opened a case regarding the missing feature). Is there any other way to play custom sounds that identify the sender of a newly-received message in Messages?  Failing that, are there any similar applications (I prefer a free one) that are able to play custom sounds for newly-received messages from different message senders, and that support the XMPP protocol (used by Google Talk and similar services)?

Comment: Have you tried the "ringtone" and "text tone" settings in Contacts? Those settings may be reflected in Messages.app too?

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing those, unfortunately they seem to have no effect on Messages (which makes me wonder what they are supposed to control).

Comment: For now I am using Adium (https://adium.im/) because it gives back much of what is now missing in Messages and it is very configurable.  The only real downsides are that it looks a bit ugly in its default configuration (IMHO) but if you spend time configuring it, it can be made to look much better, and that it won't do iMessage chats because that's an Apple proprietary format.  So I have to run both Messages (for iMessage) and Adium (for the other protocols) but at least it all works.  I wish there were a better alternative but so far I have not found one.